# xlwings activate variable sheet name

Tags: xlwings

I'm trying to perform two actions:
1) Check to see if a worksheet exists in a workbook using xlwings
2) Use a variable name to activate the worksheet using xlwings.

The worksheet name is a variable, so I can't use the sheets[0] option or sheets['name'] option.

```
import xlwings as xw
app = xw.apps.active
wb = app.books.active
key1 = 'BUS'
if key1 in wb:
    sht = wb.sheets.activate(key1)
else:
    sht = wb.sheets.add(key1)
```

I get the error:
AttributeError: 'Sheets' object has no attribute 'activate'

Answer (score 1):

You should slightly rewrite your code to get this working. Tested this by opening a new Excel workbook and running the code a few times.

```
# python 3.7.3
# xlwings 0.15.8

import xlwings as xw

app = xw.apps.active
wb = app.books.active

key1 = 'BUS'

if key1 in [sh.name for sh in wb.sheets]:
    sht = wb.sheets[key1]
else:
    sht = wb.sheets.add(key1)
```

**Changes**:

- You should iterate over the sheet names instead of the sheet objects
- There is no need to activate a sheet in `xlwings`. As soon as you assign the sheet you want to work in to your `sht` variable, all actions will be performed on this sheet. You can also create a separate variable for every sheet (e.g. `sht_bus`, `sht_train`, ...)